# How can I run "fire and forget" tasks from a controller without test warnings?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix app, I have a module function like `Reviews.create(attributes)`. It does some work immediately, and starts a task (using `Task.async`) to do additional work.

I can test it like this:

```
{:ok, new_review, task} = Reviews.create(attrs)
# verify that new_review is correct
Task.await(task)
# verify that the task did what it should
```

However, the main place I want to use `Reviews.create/1` is from a controller. From there, I want to treat the task as "fire and forget". This is simple: I just don't call `Task.await`.

This works fine, except that when I test the controller, I get errors like:

```
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.344.0>) disconnected: ** 
(DBConnection.ConnectionError) owner #PID<0.753.0> exited
while client #PID<0.755.0> is still running with: shutdown
```

In other words, it's telling me that the task got killed when the controller test ended. Which I don't care about.

Is there some way to make this more explicitly "fire and forget"? Eg, it would be nice if, from the controller, I could call `Task.forget_about(task)`, but that doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that instead of a Task, I could send messages to a GenServer, and explicitly stop and start it in my tests, but that sounds a bit complex. Especially given that what I want is *simpler* than the default Task behavior - do the thing, and don't bother supervising it.

Comment: I thought I had this figured out, but depending on timing, I still sometimes got the errors in tests. I think if I understood database pooling and supervision better, I could fix it, but for now, I'm just doing the work synchronously (no task).

Answer (score 8):

You will want to use [`Task.start/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#start/1) instead. It basically acts the same way, it just runs your function in a different process, but it will not be linked in any way to the process that spawns it.

Directly from the documentation

> This is only used when the task is used for side-effects (i.e. no interest in the returned result) and it should not be linked to the current process.

Comment: You were closer than I was. I've since found that `Task.Supervisor.async_nolink` is even better for my case, because I *can* wait for the task in a test if I *want* to verify its results. However, both of them fix the fatal flaw with my previous plan: because `Task.async` links to the parent process, when a Phoenix request completes and the request handling process dies, the task would be killed, too!

Answer (score 4):

### Use Task.Supervisor.async_nolink/2

[`Task.Supervisor.async_nolink/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#async_nolink/2) does what I wanted here:

> Starts a task that can be awaited on.

This means that I can call `Task.await(task)` in tests where I care to.

However, it also means that there's "no link" to the process that starts the task.

**This is actually important, and the test failures were telling me so**, though I didn't realize it. An incoming request is handled by a process which dies after the response has been sent. So if the background job is linked to that process, it will die, too.

To do this, I had to first add this to my supervision tree:

```
supervisor(Task.Supervisor, [[name: MyApp.TaskSupervisor]])
```

The `name:` is just an atom; it doesn't mean that I have to have a module by that name.

Then I was able to call:

```
Task.Supervisor.async_nolink(
  MyApp.TaskSupervisor,
  fn -> do_whatever end
 )
```

Comment: You should consider either change the question to mention that you want a task supervised, or accept the answer by @JustinWood, which is the best suit for the original question as it is stated. Involving `Task.Supervisor` has a ton of other issues.

Comment: @mudasobwa I disagree. My original question showed using `Task.await(task)` in a test to verify what was done. According to the docs, `Task.start/1` "is only used when the task is used for side-effects (i.e. no interest in the returned result)". As far as I know, `Task.Supervisor.async_nolink/2` is the only way to 1) not link the task to the current process but 2) allow waiting on it if desired. If there is a way to do that which does not require supervision, feel free to create an answer explaining how.

Comment: Maybe I just failed to understand what “fire and forget” means. I thought “forget” (followed by the detailed explanation: “This is simple: I just don't call `Task.await`.”) does not mean you are explicitly interested to verify what was done. I am not a native speaker, there could be issues with me understanding what you were asking.

Comment: @mudasobwa No, you understood "fire and forget" correctly. But there are two use cases in the original question. "I can test it like this..." (shows waiting on the task in a test) and "From [the controller], I want to treat the task as 'fire and forget'...". In other words, in the test, I did want to call `Task.await`, and in the controller, I didn't.